# cannot find module error in using react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Line no.3 below, I got unexpected cannot find module error in my console. It's so strange, my code and file structure look just fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import UserList from '../containers/user-list';
import UserDetail from '../containers/user-detail';
require('../../scss/style.scss');

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <h2>Username List:</h2>
        <UserList></UserList>
        <hr />
        <h2>User details</h2>
        <UserDetail />
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes in line 4, do this: var style = require('../../scss/style.scss');

Comment: @Codesingh uh? can write full code and explain? I tried it doesn't work.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Were is app.js in your directory.

Comment: yes where is app.js in your directory

Comment: @DirtyRedz  './components/app.js'

Answer (score 0):

As per es5 syntax you can not require like this in line 4 you have to code like this:

If your app.js is in components then it would solve your problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import UserList from '../containers/user-list';
import UserDetail from '../../containers/user-detail';
var style = require('../../../scss/style.scss');

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <h2>Username List:</h2>
        <UserList></UserList>
        <hr />
        <h2>User details</h2>
        <UserDetail />
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: what exactly happend ?

Comment: This is not true, you can require a file without applying a variable to it.

Comment: Requiring without a variable is useful if you want to run the code in the file with out expecting anything in return.  Now in this case since it's a css file you want the require to return the styles so you would assign a variable to it. Besides he's Hajime issues with line 3 not 4

Comment: but if you need to use you had to assign require to the variable

Comment: i think you are entering to the wrong directory to search module

Comment: where is your app.js module?

Comment: './components/app';